# Is there a way to better represent the data below?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdXx6.png)

I feel like the way i did feels abit inefficient but im not sure how to better represent the data side by side, while comparing different product and different column categories

Comment: Hey, could you show the way you represented the data? we can't guess...

Comment: Welcome to stack Overflow, Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the data so we can help

Comment: Please don't post code/data/error messages as images. Post the text directly here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no expected output, we propose an approach to create multiple graphs grouped into one. I converted your data to vertical format and grouped them by category type; for the y-axis, the income value is too large in normal format to see the other values. So I have changed it to log format.Kindly refer to [this](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/grouped_barplot.html).

```
data2 = data.melt(id_vars='Product', var_name='item', value_vars=['Education', 'Usage', 'Fitness', 'Income', 'Miles'])

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = sns.catplot(
    data=data2, kind="bar",
    x="Product", y="value", hue="item",
    palette="dark", alpha=.6, height=6
)
g.despine(left=True)
g.ax.set_yscale('log')
g.set_axis_labels("x labels", "y labels")
g.legend.set_title("legend title")
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: thanks alot for the advice. Never knew seaborn had grouped bar plots and the pandas melt function is quite new to me, definitely gotta study that function and see how to apply it. Thanks for your help once again!